# Oracle session kill issue ORA-04021

Tags: oracle11g

I received an error when I tried to drop a stored procedure. The error stated, ORA-04021 timeout occurred while waiting to lock object. So I contacted my Oracle DBA Administrator to request to kill the session that's causing the error. After she told me, she killed the session, I attempted again to drop the stored procedure and received the same error message prior to her killing the session. So I ran two queries to see if the stored procedure populates in the v$session, v$process or v$locked_object views. Nothing came back from the query. What could possibly be going wrong? (F.Y.I. I don't have system admin privileges to kill the session. I just trying to figure... if my DBA told me she kill the session, why do I keep getting ORA-04021?)

--I ran this first--

```
select blocking_session, sid, serial#, username, machine, program, process
from v$session
where sid = (select blocking_Session
             from v$session
             where blocking_session = 'VALID');
```

--Than this--

```
select s.sid, s.serial#, p.spid
from v$session s, v$process p
where s.paddr = p.addr
  and s.sid in (select session_id
                from v$locked_object);
```